# System in Superposition, Subsystem in Eigenstate: are the variables real/determined or non-real/undeterminate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, superposition

As far as I can tell, this is all textbook Quantum Mechanics, no interpretations were assumed.

Isolated system $S$ is divided into 2 isolated, separable sub-systems: $Particle$ and $Observer$.

$Particle$ is in a pure state, that is a superposition in the $B$ basis: $|b1> + |b2>$. $Observer$ is in a pure state: $|Ready to detect>$.

Then, $S$ is in a pure state, expressed as a product of the two isolated sub-system states: $(|b1> + |b2>) * (|Ready to detect>)$

$Observer$ interacts with $Particle$ and measures the $B$ observable. He detects $b1$. He becomes entangled with the particle. System $S$ is now no longer separable.

Then, isolated system $S$ remains in a pure state, now expressed as the superposition: $|b1/detected b1> + |b2/detected b2>$.

- Since $S$ is in that superposition, **the information about which of those eigenstates is the real one, does not exist**. It is not merely an unknown hidden variable (to an outsider), it literally does not exist. Whether the $Particle$ was detected in $b1$ by the $Observer$, or detected in $b2$, is literally undetermined.
- But, at the same time, the $Observer$ has already made the measurement. **He detected $b1$. The information exists.** There's a determinate answer: $b1$ & $detectedb1$. An outsider simply *doesn't know it yet*. This is expressed as tracing out either the $Particle$ or the $Observer$, obtaining a statistical mixture of eigenstates.

**How can both those statements simultaneously be valid? Either [the $Particle$ was $b1$ and $Observer$ detected $b1$], *or*, [it's indeterminate/non-real/a superposition of both]. But how can it be both at the same time? The same information exist *and* not exist?**

Furthermore, since $S$ is in a superposition of $|b1/detected b1> + |b2/detected b2>$, there's a very real possibility that an outsider could measure $|b2/detected b2>$, completely overwriting the original $Observer$'s experiences and memories. Is this what QM states? Or is the outsider guaranteed to make the same detections as the insider? But then, wasn't it just a hidden variable, instead of a superposition?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing and matching between different interpretations of QM here and, possibly unsurprisingly, this can give contradictory results. Which of your statements is true (if either) will depend on which interpretation of QM you are using.

So, for example, if you have some sort of objective collapse interpretation then when a measurement is made the wavefunction will collapse into some definite state and the system will be in one state or the other, say $|b_1/\text{detected}\;b_1\rangle$, with no $b_2$ component. There is no superposition after the measurement and all the measured quantities have taken well defined values.

If, on the other hand, you take a many-worlds style interpretation then the state after the measurement is the entangled state $|b_1/\text{detected}\;b_1\rangle + |b_2/\text{detected}\;b_2\rangle$. In this case it is not true to say that the observer has measure the state $b_1$ or that this information exists. The observer is part of the entangled superposition along with the system.

There are many interpretations of QM (too many to do any sort of exhaustive list), all of which will have their own ways of resolving this question. Some go with your first statement being true, some go with the second, some say the question is meaningless, some find their own answers.